# inserting date time with microsecond into SQL Server from python

Tags: python, sql-server, datetime, insert, pypyodbc

Below code works perfectly:

```
import pypyodbc
import datetime

connection = pypyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
    'Server=some_server;'
    'Database=some_db')
cur = connection.cursor()
some_time = datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
query = "insert into table_a (date_created) values ('"+some_time+"')"
cur.execute(query)
connection.commit()
connection.close()
```

But if I change (adding microseconds to date)

```
some_time = datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

it generates error:

```
DataError: ('22007', '[22007] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.')
```

`date_created` column is of datetime type and does display microseconds.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Humor me... 
Does inserting a hard coded string instead of the variable with milliseconds work? Does setting some_time to a string '2018-09-25 11:45:30.123' work without going through the datetime conversions?

Comment: @TEEKAY correct, the following works fine: `some_time = datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`

Comment: cannot you just use GETDATE() on insert?

Answer (score 4):

SQL Server [datetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) columns are only able to store fractional seconds to **millisecond** precision (3 decimal places). When you do

```python
some_time = datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

you get a string formatted to the precision of Python's `datetime`, which is microseconds (6 decimal places)

```python
>>> some_time
'2018-09-28 16:38:14.344801'
```

and SQL server doesn't like the extra three decimal places.

The solution is to **not** format the `datetime` as a string, just pass the `datetime` value itself in a proper *parameterized query*

```python
query = "insert into table_a (date_created) values (?)"
params = (datetime.datetime.utcnow(), )
cur.execute(query, params)
```